# JDBC Timeout with Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, performance, jdbc

Is it possible to find out which query was executing/waiting in Oracle db when JDBC timeout was issued for a session?

I checked the sessions and I can see P2TEXT = 'interrupt' and P3TEXT = 'timeout' and wait_class = 'System I/O' but sql_id is blank and p2 is 0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Active Session History (ASH) data to find out what was running and when.

ASH data is based on sampling.  Don't expect to find the exact query at the exact millisecond.  But if there is a performance problem it should stick out in a query like this:

```
select username, sample_time, sql_id
from gv$active_session_history
join dba_users
    on gv$active_session_history.user_id = dba_users.user_id
where sample_time between timestamp '2017-05-20 09:00:00' and timestamp '2017-05-21 09:05:00'
order by sample_time desc;
```

That view generally only contains data for the past day, depending on how busy the system is.  If you need to go back further in time you may be able to use DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY instead.